# Position Specific Score Matrix (PSSM) in R. How do i print out the sequence with highest score?

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

## Example PSSM Matrix

DataFram (df) looks like:

```
   v1   v2  v3  v4  v5  v6  v7  v8  v9  v10 v11 v12 v13 v14 v15
A   1   2   2   1   2   1   1   2   1   2   1   0   0   2   2
T   1   1   1   2   1   1   1   0   2   2   2   2   2   0   1
G   0   2   1   1   0   0   1   0   2   2   1   2   0   1   1
C   1   1   2   2   0   1   2   2   1   0   0   1   2   2   0
```

How do i extract out the sequence with the highest score from a pssm matrix?

```
 seq = "ATGCGGCATTAT"
# split seq by 5 (in this case)
#splited = split_n(seq,5)
    # print_out: 
    #Example desire output    
    #start_from sequence value
        #0  0   ATGCG   5
        #1  1   TGCGG   4
        #2  2   GCGGC   5
        #3  3   CGGCA   6
        #4  4   GGCAT   6
        #5  5   GCATT   8
        #6  6   CATTA   9
        #7  7   ATTAT   9
```

Other way I try but error. In this case how do i retrieve the sequence with highest score?

```
        library(Biostrings)
        dna = DNAString("ATGCGGCATTATATGCGGCATTATATGCGGCATTAT")
        
        pwm = rbind(A=c(1,2,2,1,2,1,1,2,1,2,1,0,0,2,2),
                    T=c(1,1,1,2,1,1,1,0,2,2,2,2,2,0,1),
                    G=c(0,2,1,1,0,0,1,0,2,2,1,2,0,1,1),
                    C=c(1,1,2,2,0,1,2,2,1,0,0,1,2,2,0))
                    
        pwm = pwm + 1
        i = 1
        while (i <= ncol(pwm)) {
              pwm[,i]<-pwm[,i]/sum(pwm[,i])
              i = i + 1
        }
        pssm = log2(pwm/0.25)
        scores = PWMscoreStartingAt(pssm, dna, starting.at=1:(length(dna)-ncol(pwm)+1))
    #Error in .normargPwm(pwm) : 'rownames(pwm)' must be the 4 DNA bases ('DNA_BASES')
   #print(max(scores)) 
   #print(which.max(scores))
   #in this case how do i retrieve the sequence with highest score 
   #print the sequence with highest score
```

Comment: I'm not a bioinformatician. Please be more specific on a programming aspect of the problem.

Comment: >seq= "ATGCGGCATTAT"  Thats the query sequence. In this case i have  split seq by 5 ( desire output) i.e splited into ['ATGCG', 'TGCGG', 'GCGGC', 'CGGCA', 'GGCAT', 'GCATT', 'CATTA', 'ATTAT']. And calculate  the values in each splited sequence from a matrix (df).

Comment: And how did you calculate it? ie why is ATGCG  == 3

Comment: For `ATGCG` i'm calculating 5

Comment: Example for Sl.No.1-> ATGCG calculated [("A",position 1)+("T",Position2)+("G",position 3)+("C", Position 4)+("G"+Position5)];

Comment: it should be ATGCG = 7
TGCGG = 7
GCGGC = 7
CGGCA = 7
GGCAT = 5
GCATT = 3
CATTA = 1
ATTAT = 2

Comment: So what numbers exactly are you adding up to get 7 for ATGCG? I believe to us ("A",position n) sounds like the first row and column n or n-1, but neither gives 7 for ATGCG.

Comment: @Paul make sure you update/edit your Question. It can get messy in the comments section.

Comment: df = df + 1
i = 1
while (i <= ncol(df)) {
  df[,i]<-df[,i]/sum(df[,i])
  i = i + 1
}
pssm = log2(df/0.25)
scores = dfscoreStartingAt(pssm, dna, starting.at=1:(length(seq)-ncol(df)+1))

Comment: "ATGCG" (A,1)=2, (T,2)=1,(G,3)=0,(C,4)=2,(G,5)=2; i.e(2+1+0+2+2=7)

Comment: Shouldn't "TGCGG" have a score of 8 (start at position 5 of the pssm)?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer: (too messy to write in the comments)

You're matrix should be defined something like this:

#### The first column is the first position!!!

```
df<-
fread("rname   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
A   2   1   0   1   2   0   1   0   2
      T   1   1   0   0   2   1   2   1   0
      G   1   0   0   2   2   2   2   1   2
      C   1   2   1   2   0   0   1   0   2",header=T) %>% data.frame(., row.names=1)
```

looks like

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9
A  2  1  0  1  2  0  1  0  2
T  1  1  0  0  2  1  2  1  0
G  1  0  0  2  2  2  2  1  2
C  1  2  1  2  0  0  1  0  2
```

Then use "matrix numeric index" from `?"["`

> `m[cbind(c(1,2,1),3:1)]# matrix numeric index`

for e.g.

```
library(magrittr)
x <- "ATGCG"
m <- strsplit(x,"",fixed=T)[[1]] %>% sapply(function(x) which(c("A","T","G","C") %in% x ))

IND <- cbind(m,seq_along(m))

sum(df[IND])  #evals to 7
```

Have fun playing around with this and making your own super function.